# Problems with displaying random number array

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm trying to display the random numbers that were generated into the array, but the output only displays one number multiple times. I was debugging the code and saw that the array was creating random numbers into it though. I've tried looking online for an answer but nothing seems to allow me to display the random numbers. I'm a super noob and am getting confused. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

```
main()
{
int unSortedNumbers[10] = { 0 },  i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < US; i++){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    unSortedNumbers[i] = LB + rand() % (UB - LB + 1);
}
for (i = 0; i < US; i++)
    printf("number %i) is %i.\n", i, unSortedNumbers[i]);
    pause;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `srand` before the loop:

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < US; i++){
    unSortedNumbers[i] = LB + rand() % (UB - LB + 1);
}
```

First of all, `srand` is supposed to be called once before generating a random sequence.

Second, to explain what you observed, `time` returns [`time_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/):

> For historical reasons, it is generally implemented as an integral value representing the number of seconds elapsed since ....

So perhaps all calls to `time` happen within the same second and `srand` was initialized with the same seed. Hence the same numbers.

Comment: You are a hero of men! Thank you so much, It's working perfectly!

Comment: @Brandon I just added a couple of lines to explain possible reason of the same numbers. (Regardless of the fact that `srand` should be used once.)